# How does hideous zippleback bodies work?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

I always wanted to know this and never found an answer...

In *How to Train Your Dragon*, How does their body work? Does one head control the whole body (except for the other head, neck and tail)? or does each head control the side they are on? Or does one head control the wings (and its tail) and the other head control the legs (and their tail).

I really want to know the answer but not from anything non-canon or the book.

Answer (score 1):

This has never been explained or addressed directly in the movies or series.

But when the heads or their riders disagree on what to do, no head overrules the other, and it usually ends in a crash. So it does seems like both heads control the body together.